# Hierarchical priority index

Tags: c++, indexing, data-structures, priority-queue

I am looking for an library for C++ which has indexing solution of the following problem. I have tried to make my own solution, but came to conclusion that I am inventing a wheel here.

I have source bucket which receive water. It need to split water between hierarchical structure. It can be represented also as a queue with priority, I suppose. Until a bucket with higher priority is full, other buckets do not receive any water. Some buckets have *children* buckets, where they shoud pass the water. All children can have their children as well so they are mothers for some as well. *Mother* bucket can pass water in a strict queue (one after another) or share water proportionally.

On a picture below I tried to illustrate the situation. We have ***Bucket*** as a top of the hierrachy. It has ***3 children***. They receive water in strict order according to their priority (1, 2, 3). Bucket 2 will not receive any water until Bucket 1 will be full. Bucket 1 has 3 children as well. Two kids with the same priority and split of 50% and 50% and third child which will have water only after other two will be full. First kid has kids and they split water by 20% and 80%.

Integer number 1 on any level has highest priority. Should the buckets have similar integer on the same level, we can consider their priority equal and then look at the proportion of split. Bucket with number 1 on the first level will receive water first. Then it will have to pass water to second level, where water will be split 50%-50% and then 50% will be split between last level by (20% and 80%) of 50%.

```
                                             +--------------+
                                             |              |
                                             |   Bucket     |
                                             +-+-----+----+-+
                                               |     |    |
                                               |     |    |
                                      1        |     |    |       3
                              +----------------+     |    +-----------------+
                              |                      |                      |
                              |                      |2                     |
                              ^                      |                      ^
                           +------+                  |                   +--+--+
                           |  |   |                  ^                   |     |
                  1        |  |   |   2           +--+--+                +-----+
                  0.5      |  |   |               |     |
                +----------+  |1  +-------+       +-----+
                |             |0.5        |
                ^             ^           ^
             +--+--+      +---+---+     +-+---+
             |     |      |       |     |     |
             ++-+--+      +-------+     +-----+
              | |
     1 0.2    | |
   +----------+ |1 0.8
   |            |
   |            |
   v            v
+--+--+      +--+--+
|     |      |     |
+-----+      +-----+
```

I need to index all kids and their proportion, such that, when I receive a water, I will split water according to all priorities and sharing weights. My idea was to use bits of integer part of `double` variable to represent priority on each level of the hierarchy and decimal part to store proportions.

Comment: We will not do your homework for you. You need to show your own effort, show your code, and indicate the specific problem you are encountering.

Comment: What is the precedence of buckets of different levels? For example, which fills first? the one with priority 2 on the first level or the one with priority 1 and probability 0.5 on the second level?

Comment: @SergeyA, I am asking for quite a specific question. Water and buckets are just a simplification. It is quite an abstract issue where you have hierarchical dependencies. I am not asking you to write **any** code, but to point me in right direction of looking either to family of data-structures or written frameworks.

Comment: @Cantfindname integer number 1 on any level has highest priority. Should the buckets have similar integer on the same level, we can consider their priority equal and then look at the proportion of split. Bucket with number 1 on the first level will receive water first. Then it will have to pass water to second level, where water will be split 50%-50% and then 50% will be split between last level by (20% and 80%) of 50%.

Comment: There is no data structure which will give you what you want out of the box. However, it looks  like a trivial n-tree with recursive traversal based on node priority. And by the way, when formulated like this ('I am looking for the library...') this becomes clear off-topic. Voting to close.

Comment: @SergeyA I will happily rephrase a question, should you have a suggestion how to ask it then.

Comment: The idea of using parts of a double for two different pieces of information is terrible.  Two pieces of information deserve two different members with the object.  Also, your requirements are not a good fit for any common design, so you won't find any library that does most of the job.  The whole job isn't very hard, so just code it rather than look for it to have been done before.

Comment: @JSF Sorry to hear that. In fact in my situation in all cases, I have pretty short hierarchy with no more than 3 levels and not more than 10 elements on each level. Thus, it is quite memory efficient to use just one value to store all information which is needed. Moreoever, trivial sort of the float will solve priority and split.

Comment: If you have no more than 30 object, you don't care about memory efficiency.  If you did really care about memory efficiency, it is safer and more efficient to use a fixed point fraction for proportion and use bit fields to combine the two values.

Comment: @JSF It does, i have a lot of isolated hierarchies, but anyway thanks for hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform you problem from a tree representation to a queue by traversing depth-first your tree with a visitor:

```
#include <map>
#include <list>

struct Bucket
{
    std::map<unsigned int, Bucket> children; // <priority, children>

    template<class Visitor>
    void visit(const Visitor& visitor)
    {
        for (auto it = children.rbegin(); it!= children.rend(); ++it)
        {
            visitor(&it->second);
            it->second.visit(visitor);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Bucket root_bucket;
    // populate root_bucket
    // ...

    // index root_bucket
    std::list<Bucket*> indexed_buckets;
    root_bucket.visit( [&](Bucket* b){ indexed_buckets.push_back(b); });
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d6d6a8a92b215ae)</kbd>

After that, `indexed_buckets` will contain pointers to the buckets in the filling order. Simply fill the first one until it's full and then fill the next one with remaining water.

Comment: @CronAcronis I've edited my answer with an actual code. i've also added a link to a demo.

Comment: Just to keep it aligned with question. `std::map<unsigned int, Bucket, std::greater<int>> children;` In question smaller `int` has higher priority.